# standalone web app link script - stop it from appending links which have a specific class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, web-applications

This script prevents links from opening in Mobile Safari. This is for when the web app is in app mode on iOS (home screen bookmark).

[gist.github.com/1042026](http://gist.github.com/1042026)

```
if(("standalone" in window.navigator) && window.navigator.standalone){

    // If you want to prevent remote links in standalone web apps opening Mobile Safari, change 'remotes' to true
    var noddy, remotes = false;

    document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {

        noddy = event.target;

        // Bubble up until we hit link or top HTML element. Warning: BODY element is not compulsory so better to stop on HTML
        while(noddy.nodeName !== "A" && noddy.nodeName !== "HTML") {
            noddy = noddy.parentNode;
        }

        if('href' in noddy && noddy.href.indexOf('http') !== -1 && (noddy.href.indexOf(document.location.host) !== -1 || remotes))
        {
            event.preventDefault();
            document.location.href = noddy.href;
        }

    },false);
}
```

My question is how do you get this script above to ignore links with a class?

So for example I've `a.lightbox` - and this link opens and image in a lightbox using the [www.photoswipe.com](http://www.photoswipe.com/) jquery plugin.

But when I use the script it kills the lightbox launch up and it just opens the image on its own. But if I this script above, the photoswipe lightbox works fine.

Has anyone got some suggestions or help modifiy this script to ignore these links `a.lightbox`

Thanks
Josh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using jQuery you should be able to just add `&& !$(noddy).hasClass('lightbox')` to your if test.

Comment: Sweet it works! Have posted my code above for reference. Thanks dude