# standalone web app link script - stop it from appending links which have a specific class? bis

Tags: jquery, web-applications, iphone-standalone-web-app

Following the discussion -> this thread:
[standalone web app link script - stop it from appending links which have a specific class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16116050/standalone-web-app-link-script-stop-it-from-appending-links-which-have-a-speci)

--> https://gist.github.com/kylebarrow/1042026

```
if(("standalone" in window.navigator) && window.navigator.standalone){ // If you want to prevent remote links in standalone web apps opening Mobile Safari, change 'remotes' to true
    var noddy, remotes = false; document.addEventListener('click', function(event) { noddy = event.target;

        // Bubble up until we hit link or top HTML element. Warning: BODY element is not compulsory so better to stop on HTML
        while(noddy.nodeName !== "A" && noddy.nodeName !== "HTML") {
            noddy = noddy.parentNode;
        }

        if('href' in noddy && noddy.href.indexOf('http') !== -1 && (noddy.href.indexOf(document.location.host) !== -1 || remotes))
        {
            event.preventDefault();
            document.location.href = noddy.href;
        }

    },false); }
```

Is Does anyone can help me? I have the same problem but i can't get to solve it with this code ->

```
&& !$(noddy).hasClass('lightbox')
```

I do not know where exactly I can add it in the script on top?

Any idea to solve it? or Is there another solution?

Best,
Lina

Comment: I think you need to provide more details. Try posting the code you are using so we know there are no differences from the other question.

Comment: ............................................................-  :-( sorry!  Any idea to solve it? plz